# React - Rails. Rails session[:user_id] not persisting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs

I am building a React - Rails API application. Following a tutorial, I *intentionally* did not instantiate Rails as an API, rather it's the full framework. So, according to the the tutorial giver, I should have access to session and not have to download any gems.

**Problem:** When I refresh the page the session should keep the user logged in. It is not. Instead of returning with: `{ logged_in: true, user: {...} }`, it is returning with `{ logged_in: false }` (the else conditional in session's logged_in method). The `@current_user` from the concern file is returning as `nil`, more specifically, its `session[:user_id]` is returning nil, so the conditional is failing.

I'm out of ideas, I've been messing with this for over an hour and still no luck. If anything else is needed please let me know.

#### Rails: Sessions Controller

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  include CurrentUserConcern

  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params["user"]["email"])
               .try(:authenticate, params["user"]["password"])

    if user
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      // binding.pry shows session[:user_id] = 4 (or whatever the id is)
      render json: {
        status: :created,
        logged_in: true,
        user: user
      }
    else
      render json: { status: 401 }
    end
  end

  // Method in question:
  def logged_in
    // @current_user == nil
    if @current_user
      render json: {
        logged_in: true,
        user: @current_user
      }
    else
      render json: {
        logged_in: false
      }
    end
  end

  def logout
    reset_session
    render json: { status: 200, logged_out: true }
  end
end
```

#### Rails: controllers/concerns/current_user_concern.rb

```
module CurrentUserConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_action :set_current_user
  end

  def set_current_user
    if session[:user_id]
    // binding.pry shows session[:user_id] = nil
      @current_user = User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
    end
  end
end
```

#### React: App.js

```
// Method that is interacting with Rails
checkLoginStatus = () => {
    axios
       .get('http://localhost:3001/logged_in', { withCredentials: true })
          .then((response) => {
            // Does not enter the conditions RESPONSE = data.logged_in: false
            if (response.data.logged_in && this.state.loggedInStatus === 'NOT_LOGGED_IN') {
                this.setState({ loggedInStatus: 'LOGGED_IN', user: response.data.user });
            } else if (!response.data.logged_in && this.state.loggedInStatus === 'LOGGED_IN') {
                this.setState({ loggedInStatus: 'NOT_LOGGED_IN', user: {} });
            }
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log('hello error.', error));
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the following `config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Cookies
config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore` to config/application.rb